# Error al intentar seleccionar campo en mi tabla gridview webform c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

El código de mi gridview es este:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="ListaArticulos" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" OnRowCommand="ListaArticulos_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField AccessibleHeaderText="Eliminar" Text="Eliminar" CommandName="CellEliminar"/>
        <asp:ButtonField AccessibleHeaderText="Editar" Text="Editar" CommandName="CellEditar"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IDArticulo" HeaderText="Clave" SortExpression="Clave" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NombreArticulo" HeaderText="Articulo" SortExpression="Articulo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Abreviado" HeaderText="Abreviado" SortExpression="Abreviado"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Precio" HeaderText="Precio" SortExpression="Precio" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CantidadArticulo" HeaderText="Cantidad" SortExpression="Cantidad" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

y mi método es este:

```
 protected void ListaArticulos_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string idPro;

        /*if (e.CommandName == "CellEliminar")
        {

        }*/
        if(e.CommandName == "CellEditar")
        {
            idPro = ListaArticulos.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text; //<-error aquí
            txtBuscar.Text = idPro;
            //Redireccionar(idPro);
        }
    }
```

Cuando intento acceder al campo me sale este error, dice que no hago referencia a un objeto, ¿pero cual objeto?

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ComprasWebForm.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Referencia a objeto no establecida como
>   instancia de un objeto.

Como solución me pide hacer referencia con new, ¿alguien me explique que esta pasando o que hago mal?

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

Creo que no es la forma correcta de acceder a los campos del gridview. Te adjunto bloque de código que permite obtener los valores desde la grilla.

```
void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) if(e.CommandName=="Add")
{
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];

  ListItem item = new ListItem();
  item.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text) + " " +
    Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[3].Text);

  if (!ContactsListBox.Items.Contains(item))
  {
    ContactsListBox.Items.Add(item);
  }
}
```